# Can I use implicitly instantiated member functions from another translation unit

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation

Without optimization flags, the following code compiles fine, but with `-O1` both g++ and clang++ throw `undefined reference to 'void Foo::Fooify<int>(int)'`

Adding an explicit instantiation in `foo.cpp` solves the issue, but that seems redundant to me after an implicit instantiation. Is it really necessary to do that or are the compiler optimizations at fault here?

```
//foo.h

struct Foo {
  template <class T>
  void Fooify(T);
  void UseFooifyForInt();
};
```

```
//foo.cpp

#include foo.h

template <class T>
void Foo::Fooify(T) {}

void Foo::UseFooifyForInt() {
  Fooify(5);
}
```

```
//main.cpp

#include foo.h

int main() {
  Foo f{};
  f.Fooify(42);
}
```

This question is currently marked as a duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file), but one of the solutions given there is to explicitly instantiate the templates in the .cpp file (in my case that would be `foo.cpp`. I am wondering why an implicit instantiation does not work for this use case.

Comment: The compiler will inline `Fooify` in `foo.cpp` so won't export the symbol

Comment: If you remove `Fooify(5);` from `foo.cpp` then at the point when you wrote `f.Fooify(42);` the linker doesn't have the definition of `Foo::Fooify(T)` as the header only has a declaration for that member function and not the definition and hence you get the mentioned linker error. On the other hand, if you have `Fooify(5);` in `foo.cpp` then that member functions will be instantiated and hence its definition is available and so `f.Fooify(42);` will work here without any linker error in this case.

Comment: @AnoopRana only if compiler optimisations are disabled

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks for the comment. So is it correct to say that it's unsafe to rely on implicit instantiations because the compiler might inline those, making them unavailable? While an explicit instantiation would never be inlined?

Comment: Yes, explicit instantiations signal your intent to use the template elsewhere, implicit ones don't so the compiler happily throws them away

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks! It surprises me that a compiler optimization can change observable behavior like this though. Doesn't that violate the as-if rule? Or would you rather say my program is malformed without the explicit instantiation?

Comment: Yep, it's malformed and just happens to work without optimisations enabled